# Database of Japanese meibutsu, with locality and since when

Tags: data-request, food, japan

Almost any town in Japan has its own "speciality food" called meibutsu.

Is there a database of containing for each town its meibutsu(s)?

- Ideally each item should also say since when the meibutsu has been produced in this city, as many meibutsu are actually recent inventions designed specifically to cash on passing travellers.
- A picture would also be great.
- Quantity produced and distributing brands would be wonderful.

Information can be in Japanese or any language.

Comment: Oh, noms! I had no idea this was a thing...

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a short list of meibutsu sorted by region:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokusanhin

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%89%B9%E7%94%A3%E5%93%81

Unfortunately it is very short, too coarse-grained, does not contain dates, and most meibutsu are lacking.

Answer (score 1):

This travel guide site https://gurutabi.gnavi.co.jp/i/gm101/ have a collection of 1918 entries about meibutsu meals from different area all around Japan sorted by popularity.

Most entries have info about the food in Japanese including area that the food is famous in and time that the food is suitable to be consumed. Most of them also include a short summary. But there are little info about when it start become popular unless it's describe in the summary.

And then, Rurubu the famous Japanese travel guide publisher have also selected ~250 such meals on their website http://www.rurubu.com/season/special/gourmet/ . While this site have less entry than the previous one, they're probably more carefullu selected, and there are also link to list of shops that supply each of those foods together with relevant map and contact method and such.

Or, perhaps another way to look at it is to look at what each town is offering to supporters in the Furusato tax campaign: https://www.furusato-tax.jp